# Finding and manipulating a UI control with a particular Name

Tags: c#, wpf

OK so I have to work with lots of toggle button and textbox, so I named them in such way that adding letter "Q" to button's name will give name of the textbox that the button corresponds to. I have link all the button to the same method on checked event, and using this naming mechanism I, hope to manipulate the textbox corresponding the button.

What I have done till now is, generate an name of the textbox in string format. But i don't know to how to use this string to manipulate the textbox.

```
private void OnbuttonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton)sender;
        if(tb.IsChecked==true)
        {
            string tbnam = ((ToggleButton)sender).Name;
            string name2 = tbnam + "Q";

            ?????? (what happens from this point onward)
        }
    }
```

"name2" is the name of textbox that corresponds to the toggle button of name "tbnam".

I hope the I have made the problem clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, a much better way to do this would to expose a collection of objects in the viewmodel, and display in the UI with an `ItemsControl` with an `ItemTemplate` that would dynamically create as many iterations of `ToggleButton`/`TextBox` pairs as needed. I'd be happy to go into how to do that, if you're interested.

But for now, you can get your code working using the `FindName(string)` method:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton)sender;
    if (tb.IsChecked == true)
    {
        string name2 = tb.Name + "Q";

        TextBox tbox = FindName(name2) as TextBox;

        //  Check to see if tbox is null, do stuff with it
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like the textbox by that name isn't really there in the same window. In my testing, that code worked. Can you provide enough of your XAML for me to test the same case that you've got?

Comment: OH i found the mistake